# Is there a display manager for Philips monitors?

Tags: display

I recently bought a Philips monitor. My previous monitor was Dell, and now I realize that my favorite thing about that monitor was the [DDP](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000060112/what-is-dell-display-manager) (Dell Display Manager). It is a simple software
which lets the user control the brightness, contrast, gamma, etc. without having to press the physical buttons on the monitor.

I really would love to have such a software for my new Philips monitor as well. I have checked thoroughly, but I could not find such a software. Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ITNOA

Philips monitor normally has two software

- Driver
- SmartControl Software - [Example of download link](https://www.usa.philips.com/c-p/272E1GSJ_27/gaming-monitor/support)

SmartControl is a software utility that allows monitor adjustment and color tuning using the Display Data Channel Command Interface (DDC/CI) protocol.

Comment: Although that software is designed for another model, it works perfectly for my monitor too! Thanks!